# Are Franca IDL files and Fuchsia's FIDL files related in any way?

Tags: fuchsia, franca

I was exposed to files with a `.fidl` extension for the first time a few years ago as part of a project that used the [Franca](http://franca.github.io/franca/) framework for IPC. Recently, I was spelunking around Google's Fuchsia project and learned that it, too, uses 'FIDL files' for IPC, see:

- https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/docs/+/master/development/languages/fidl/README.md

My question is: are these FIDL variants related in any way, i.e., do they share a common genesis, or... is a complete coincidence that "Fuchsia IDL" and "Franca IDL" both abbreviate to "FIDL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody answered my question in the [Franca Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/franca-framework/TjgMXXLWHfc/BlxntKisAgAJ): Franca's FIDL files and Fuchsia's FIDL files are completely unrelated. It's just a coincidence that they have the same extension, and a similar purpose.